# How to prevent object from being reinitialized everytime it is invoked? - Dart / Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

For the snippet of the code below:

// snippet of the main class

```
class MainState extends State<Main>{

MusicMaterial musicObj = MusicMaterial();
SoundsMaterial soundObj = SoundsMaterial();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
          child: something.value == 0
              ? musicObj 
              : soundObj
        );
  }
}
```

// snippet of the MusicMaterial class

```
class MusicMaterialState extends State<MusicMaterial>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
          AnotherClass obj1 = AnotherClass(0, 'test'),  
          AnotherClass obj2 = AnotherClass(1, 'test'),
        );
  }
}
```

// snippet of the AnotherClass class

```
class AnotherClassState extends State<AnotherClass>{
import '../globals.dart' as globals;

@override
  void initState() {
    globals.globalCounter++;  // this variable is just a global variable from the globals.dart page
}

}
```

// snippet of the global.dart

```
library my_prj.globals;

globalCounter = 0;
```

It keeps creating a new instance every time the "if" state is updated in the Main State class. So for instance, the value of the global counter keeps going up from 0 to 2 to 4...8... How do we ensure that the object does not get re-initialized every single time, so for instance void initState() from AnotherClassState is called only once? i.e the value remains 2 and only 2.

I have tried using "AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin and  @override  bool get wantKeepAlive => true" - i.e keeping it alive so when it is invoked next time, it does not call initState() again, however it did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully I'm understanding correctly what you need. It seems that you want the counter to be increased only one time per class type. I'm sure there are different ways to do it but It comes to my mind to make `globalCounter` a little more complex

```
class GlobalCounter {
  List<String> _keys = List<String>();
  int _counter = 0;

  int get counter => _counter;

  void increaseCounter(String key) {
    // increase only if the key passed as parameter didn't increase already
    if (!_keys.contains(key)) {
      _counter++;
      _keys.add(key);
    }
  }
}

globalCounter = GlobalCounter();
```

Then you can use it like this

```
@override
void initState() {
    // pass the type of the instance trying to increase the counter
    globals.globalCounter.increaseCounter(this.runtimeType.toString()); 
}
```