# Flutter | How to prevent object elements of a list from being reinitialized everytime they are accessed?

Tags: flutter, dart

user is supposed to see a new card (CardExample) eveytime s/he swipes left. but in my case, when the card is swiped left and then right again, -when the previous card is supposed to pop out- a new card is always generated.
so i'm kind of suspicious about the *cards* list. i think the element of index i is always reinitialized when it's invoked. but i still don't now.

i was using Stateless widget for CardExample. then i changed it into Stateful to try out ValueKey as a solution. however it didn't work out.

i know about the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62844557/how-to-prevent-object-from-being-reinitialized-everytime-it-is-invoked-dart) but it's not really an answer to my problem.

ExampleRoute.dart :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:swipeable_card/swipeable_card.dart';

import 'card_example.dart';

class ExampleRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExampleRoute({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExampleRouteState createState() => _ExampleRouteState();
}

class _ExampleRouteState extends State<ExampleRoute> {
  List<CardExample> cards;
  int currentCardIndex;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    cards = [
      CardExample(key: ValueKey(0)),
      CardExample(key: ValueKey(1)),
      CardExample(key: ValueKey(2)),
    ];
    currentCardIndex = 0;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint("Card Length: ${cards.length.toString()}");
    debugPrint("Current Index: $currentCardIndex");
//  _cardController is an identifier.
    SwipeableWidgetController _cardController = SwipeableWidgetController();
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            SwipeableWidget(
              cardController: _cardController,
              animationDuration: 500,
              horizontalThreshold: 0.85,
              child: cards[currentCardIndex],
              nextCards: <Widget>[
                // show next card
                // if there are no next cards, show nothing
                if (currentCardIndex + 1 < cards.length)
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
//                    child: cards[currentCardIndex + 1],
                  ),
              ],
              onLeftSwipe: () {
                if (currentCardIndex + 1 == cards.length - 1) cards.add(CardExample(key: ValueKey(currentCardIndex + 2)));
                swipeLeft();
              },
              onRightSwipe: () {
                if (currentCardIndex != 0) swipeRight();
              },
            ),
            cardControllerRow(_cardController),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void swipeLeft() {
    debugPrint("New Question");

    // NOTE: it is your job to change the card
    setState(() {
      currentCardIndex++;
    });
  }

  void swipeRight() {
    debugPrint("Previous Question");
    setState(() {
      currentCardIndex--;
    });
  }

  Widget cardControllerRow(SwipeableWidgetController cardController) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: <Widget>[
        TextButton(
          child: Text("Previous Question"),
          onPressed: () => cardController.triggerSwipeRight(),
        ),
        TextButton(
          child: Text("New Question"),
          onPressed: () => cardController.triggerSwipeLeft(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

CardExample.dart :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class CardExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const CardExample({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CardExampleState createState() => _CardExampleState();
}

class _CardExampleState extends State<CardExample> {
  String getRandomGeneratedId() {
    const int AUTO_ID_LENGTH = 20;
    const String AUTO_ID_ALPHABET = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

    const int maxRandom = AUTO_ID_ALPHABET.length;
    final Random randomGen = Random();

    String id = '';
    for (int i = 0; i < AUTO_ID_LENGTH; i++) {
      id = id + AUTO_ID_ALPHABET[randomGen.nextInt(maxRandom)];
    }
    return id;
  }

  Future<DocumentSnapshot> getRandomQuestion() async {
    CollectionReference myRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('questions');
    // generate a random index based on the list length and use it to retrieve the element
    while (true) {
      String _randomIndex = getRandomGeneratedId();
      QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await myRef.where('id', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: _randomIndex).orderBy('id', descending: false).limit(1).get();
      debugPrint(_randomIndex);
      if (querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        DocumentSnapshot question = querySnapshot.docs[0]; // returns a DocumentSnapshot of the (random) question
        debugPrint(question.data().toString());
        return question;
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: getRandomQuestion(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text(
            snapshot.error.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 24.0,
              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
            ),
          );
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data.exists) {
          return Text("Document does not exist");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Text(
            data['text'],
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 24.0,
              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
            ),
          );
        }

        return Text("loading");
      },
    );

/*    return Container(
      height: 450,
      width: 320,

      // Warning: hard-coding values like this is a bad practice
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(38.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: color,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
        border: Border.all(
          width: 7.0,
          color: Colors.transparent.withOpacity(0.3),
        ),
      ),

      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 36.0,
          // color: Colors.white,
          color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
        ),
      ),
    );
*/
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize card controller before the build widget, inside it will reinitialize it every time the page rebuilds.

Edit: Maybe I didn't understand your question or you're just a bit  confused, I have tested your code and it worked perfectly as you described the way you want it to be, If it doesn't please illustrate the issue you're having more.

But I suppose you are referring to some data the user may insert, this is a widget that builds the data you give it to build, if you want not to lose data you will have to store it in a local variable or a database then
restore every time you want to show it again.

Edit: Future builder has nothing to do with it, it happens because you generate random id every time you swipe left or right. Here is a suggestion of how you can solve this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:swipeable_card/swipeable_card.dart';

import 'card_example.dart';

class ExampleRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExampleRoute({Key key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  _ExampleRouteState createState() => _ExampleRouteState();
}

class _ExampleRouteState extends State<ExampleRoute> {
  List<CardExample> cards;
  int currentCardIndex;
  List<String> idList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    String id;
      getRandomGeneratedId().then((value) {
        id = value;
        idList.add(id);
      });
    cards = [
      CardExample(key: ValueKey(0),question_id: idList[0],),
      CardExample(key: ValueKey(1),question_id: idList[1],),
      CardExample(key: ValueKey(2),question_id: idList[2],),
    ];
    currentCardIndex = 0;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint("Card Length: ${cards.length.toString()}");
    debugPrint("Current Index: $currentCardIndex");
//  _cardController is an identifier.
    SwipeableWidgetController _cardController = SwipeableWidgetController();
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            SwipeableWidget(
              cardController: _cardController,
              animationDuration: 500,
              horizontalThreshold: 0.85,
              child: cards[currentCardIndex],
              nextCards: <Widget>[
                // show next card
                // if there are no next cards, show nothing
                if (currentCardIndex + 1 < cards.length)
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
//                    child: cards[currentCardIndex + 1],
                  ),
              ],
              onLeftSwipe: () {
                if (currentCardIndex + 1 == cards.length - 1) cards.add(CardExample(key: ValueKey(currentCardIndex + 2)));
                swipeLeft();
              },
              onRightSwipe: () {
                if (currentCardIndex != 0) swipeRight();
              },
            ),
            cardControllerRow(_cardController),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void swipeLeft() {
    debugPrint("New Question");
    String id;

    // NOTE: it is your job to change the card
    if (idList.length <= currentCardIndex) {
      getRandomGeneratedId().then((value) {
        id = value;
        idList.add(id);
      });
    setState(() {
      currentCardIndex++;
    });
    }
  }

void swipeRight() async{
  debugPrint("Previous Question");
  setState(() {
    currentCardIndex--;
  });
}

Widget cardControllerRow(SwipeableWidgetController cardController) {
  return Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
    children: <Widget>[
      TextButton(
        child: Text("Previous Question"),
        onPressed: () => cardController.triggerSwipeRight(),
      ),
      TextButton(
        child: Text("New Question"),
        onPressed: () => cardController.triggerSwipeLeft(),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
}
class CardExample extends StatefulWidget {
  final String question_id;
  const CardExample({Key key, this.question_id}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CardExampleState createState() => _CardExampleState();
}

class _CardExampleState extends State<CardExample> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: getQuestion(widget.question_id),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text(
            snapshot.error.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 24.0,
              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
            ),
          );
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data.exists) {
          return Text("Document does not exist");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Text(
            data['text'],
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 24.0,
              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
            ),
          );
        }

        return Text("loading");
      },
    );

/*    return Container(
      height: 450,
      width: 320,

      // Warning: hard-coding values like this is a bad practice
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(38.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: color,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
        border: Border.all(
          width: 7.0,
          color: Colors.transparent.withOpacity(0.3),
        ),
      ),

      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 36.0,
          // color: Colors.white,
          color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
        ),
      ),
    );
*/
  }
}

Future<String> getRandomGeneratedId() async {
  const int AUTO_ID_LENGTH = 20;
  const String AUTO_ID_ALPHABET = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

  const int maxRandom = AUTO_ID_ALPHABET.length;
  final Random randomGen = Random();

  String id = '';
  for (int i = 0; i < AUTO_ID_LENGTH; i++) {
    id = id + AUTO_ID_ALPHABET[randomGen.nextInt(maxRandom)];
  }
  CollectionReference myRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(
      'questions');
  // generate a random index based on the list length and use it to retrieve the element
  while (true) {
    await myRef.where(
        'id', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: id).orderBy(
        'id', descending: false).limit(1).get();
    if (querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
       DocumentSnapshot question = querySnapshot.docs[0]; /
   return id;
  }
}


Future<DocumentSnapshot> getQuestion(String _randomIndex,) async {
  CollectionReference myRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('questions');
  // generate a random index based on the list length and use it to retrieve the element
  while (true) {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await myRef.where('id', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: _randomIndex).orderBy('id', descending: false).limit(1).get();
    debugPrint(_randomIndex);
    if (querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
      DocumentSnapshot question = querySnapshot.docs[0]; // returns a DocumentSnapshot of the (random) question
      debugPrint(question.data().toString());
      return question;
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. according to your answer, i took it inside of the initState() method but it doesn't seem like it worked.
`class _ExampleRouteState extends State<ExampleRoute> {SwipeableWidgetController _cardController; ...}`
`void initState() {... _cardController = SwipeableWidgetController(); ...}`

Comment: hi, thanks again for the answer. i think ExampleRoute works just fine but i guess the problem lies somewhere within CardExample. i'm using firebase firestore to fetch questions from the database randomly. i've added the code to the question (CardExample.dart). could it because of the whole Future and FutureBuilder things? but when you think about it, it should still return a Text widget in the very end. i just don't get it.